# DNS in Govcloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, itar

So I'm trying to understand how I can make routing traffic work in GovCloud

So let's say I have a web application setup like this in GovCloud

```
[LB] ---> [EC2]
```

And I want to route traffic like this

```
[route53] --> [LB] ---> [EC2]
```

From AWS docs it looks like this will be the approach

[image]

If my understanding is right, what is the logic (Compliance wise) behind having to jump from a global region to a govcloud region for routing customer traffic

Another GovCloud/Itar Question.. Are only US citizens allowed to be the web app users since the app is hosted in GovCloud?

Comment: Route 53 is a global DNS service. Your DNS requests may hit R53 but your application's network traffic doesn't.

Comment: Also, ITAR relates to [US Persons](https://exportcompliancesolutions.com/blog/2018/09/20/u-s-persons-include-just-citizens/), not just US Citizens.